# Alert dialog with edittext returns null, because it return before value is assigned

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have an app in which i want to call a method that opens a dialog with an number input, my problem is that whenever a value is inserted in the edittext and the positive button is pressed it returns a null, and then first the value on the next call.

Through debugging i've figured out that it created the element, and then returns afterward skipping my assignment statement.

How do i prevent it from returning too early?

```
private String numbers;
    private String getWeight(){
        final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("How much do you weigh?");
        builder1.setView(edittext);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    numbers = edittext.getText().toString();
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

        builder1.setNeutralButton(
                "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        numbers = edittext.getText().toString();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();

        return numbers;
    }
```

Comment: you do not need to return 'numbers' from your function, because as i found out from your code, 'numbers' is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

so put editText content in String when typing.

```
String content;
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    content = s.toString();
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
// call method
}
}
});
```

and setPositiveButton here to get content string.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and fixed it using the following approach .

You should create a static xml layout for the view. Do not build  it programmatically.

updating your code

```
private String numbers;
private String getWeight(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weight_simple_input, null);
    builder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder1.setMessage("How much do you weigh?");
    builder1.setView(mView);
    builder1.setCancelable(true);

    builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                numbers = ((EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.phone)).getText().toString();
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });

    builder1.setNeutralButton(
            "Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    numbers = edittext.getText().toString();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
}
```

And whilst you have defined numbers in the class scope, you don't need to return it again. use it wherever you want.

Finally here is the layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/weight" />
 </LinearLayout>
```